# How to install sub packages through yum

Tags: ansible

Here is what exactly i am trying to achieve. I have to install a package along with Dependencies. I am trying to install telnet package. For that two packages have to install per my requirement those are telnet and telnet-server.In some servers telnet is already installed but not telnet-server. If telnet package is already installed then it is not installing telnet-server if i pass telnet-* in the prompt. Below is the playbook execution

```
    [test@localhost ansible]$ cat prompt.yml
    --- # Install the package which is provided through command line
    - hosts: target
    user: test
    become: yes
    connection: ssh
    gather_facts: no
    vars_prompt:
    - name: pkgtoinstall
    prompt: which package need to install?
    private: no
    tasks:
    - name: Install the provided package
    yum: pkg={{ pkgtoinstall }} state=latest

[test@localhost ansible]$

Before Installation -:  

[test@localhost opt]$ rpm -qa | grep telnet  
[test@localhost opt]$  

[test@localhost ansible]$ ansible-playbook prompt.yml  
which package need to install?: telnet*  

PLAY [target]  
 ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Install the provided package] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [192.168.56.102]

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
192.168.56.102             : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0

[test@localhost ansible]$  

After Installation -:

[test@localhost opt]$ rpm -qa | grep telnet  
telnet-0.17-64.el7.x86_64
telnet-server-0.17-64.el7.x86_64
[test@localhost opt]$   

Now i have removed telnet-server manually and tried to install by giving telnet-*. It is not getting installed.

[test@localhost opt]$ sudo yum remove telnet-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package telnet-server.x86_64 1:0.17-64.el7 will be erased
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=============================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                      Arch                                  Version                                       Repository                            Size
=============================================================================================================================================================================
Removing:
 telnet-server                                x86_64                                1:0.17-64.el7                                 @base                                 55 k

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================================================================================================================
Remove  1 Package

Installed size: 55 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Erasing    : 1:telnet-server-0.17-64.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                        1/1
  Verifying  : 1:telnet-server-0.17-64.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                        1/1

Removed:
  telnet-server.x86_64 1:0.17-64.el7

Complete!
[test@localhost opt]$ rpm -qa | grep telnet
telnet-0.17-64.el7.x86_64
[test@localhost opt]$

[test@localhost ansible]$ ansible-playbook prompt.yml
which package need to install?: telnet*

PLAY [target] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Install the provided package] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.56.102]

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
192.168.56.102             : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0

[test@localhost opt]$ rpm -qa | grep telnet
telnet-0.17-64.el7.x86_64
[test@localhost opt]$
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you're looking for but I'd install the 2 packages explicitly.  Using globs for package installs has the potential of installing something you don't want or need.

```
- name: Install the provided package
  yum:
    pkg: "{{ item }}"
    state: latest
  with_items:
  - telnet
  - telnet-server
```